# Do I really need the event delegation method for css method?

Tags: jquery

The element is not dynamically added but the css is dynamically applied via jQuery's css() method. And before today I was using event delegation method only for those elements which are dynamically added not for those elements which css properties and values are applied dynamically i.e. via some scripts.

And the following wasn't working for me:

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
   el.css({.....});
   someMethod(el);
}).resize();
```

And I'm sure for those elements which css is applied via jQuery doesn't need to go with event delegation method.

But after struggling a lot the following method worked perfectly:

```
$(window.parent).on('resize',window,function(){
   el.css({.....});
   someMethod(el);
}).resize();
```

So, I'm unsure why is it necessary here to apply event delegation method?

**Update:**

As per the @jfriend00 answer, I came to know the key reason was because of the point no. 3 (event applied to multiple children with single parent).

But again without using the event delegation method the following method worked:

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
   el.css({.....});
   someMethod(el);
}).resize();//even if resize() is removed from here won't work
$(window).trigger('resize');//even it is removed from here won't work
```

That is both resize are required. Why is this so?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why you would need event delegation with the `window` object or gain anything with it.

Event delegation is useful in these circumstances:

1. The DOM objects you want to target are not yet present so you can target a parent that is present and when the event reaches the parent, the code can see if the originating object matches the selector.  This allows event handlers to work (for some events) with objects that are not yet created.
2. The DOM objects you want to target are replaced at some time after the event handlers have been installed.  This leads to the same issue as point 1 above where the newly created objects did not exist at the time the event handlers were installed.
3. When it is more efficient to apply a single event handler to a common parent that can then serve a lot of child objects, all from one event handler.

I don't see any reason why any of these methods would apply to your circumstance.  You are only listening for the `resize` event on the `window` object and the `window` object exists at the time you install the event handlers and is not replaced and you aren't trying to serve a lot of child objects at once.

Comment: Thank you very much. The key reason was because of point no. 3.

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal - But, you aren't using a selector as the 2nd argument to `.on()` so you aren't serving multiple windows.